# AngularJS ng-hide not working with html binding to a div

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I'm trying to render html content from a controller , but the angular directive ng-hide doesn't work , I've tried the following code, does it have a problem with binding as html this way?

```js
      var htmlContent = "<Div class='vzone'  ng-hide='true' id='parent_" +  ViewerZones[CurrentIndex].Id + "'...'></div>";
  
$scope.PageContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlContent);
```

```html
<div  ng-bind-html="PageContent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
 var htmlContent = "<Div class='vzone'  ng-.....

$scope.PageContent = $sce.trustAsHtml($compile(htmlContent));
```

don't forget to add `$compile` dependency in your controller.

`$compile` service will bind your dynamic directives with the controller

Comment: I tried it but gives the following exception  "Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: htmlContent"